# UIImageView or UIImage class for animating images?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

If you want to simply animate between a bunch of images included in the project, what are the reasons for using one of these two classes over the other? `UIImageView` offers the `animationImages` property while `UIImage` provides `images` property, which seems similar.

What is not clear from the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is how you actually start and stop the animations in UIImage as you would in UIIMageView. Is this perhaps a key difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView is a View class, this means it can handle user interactions and is responsible for drawing on a specific area. It actually encapsulates UIImage. Like any View class it can have subviews added to it.

On the other hand UIImage is just a representation of an Image, and since 5.0 also an animated image. It doesnt have any spatial and state properties in the context of parent UIViews.